# Scaleratio plotly

Tags: python, plotly

There is the following solution to the problem:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi, sin, cos
import plotly.graph_objects as go


def degree2rad(degrees):
    return degrees * pi / 180


def disk_part(center, radius, start_angle, end_angle, n_points=50):
    t = np.linspace(degree2rad(start_angle), degree2rad(end_angle), n_points)
    x = center[0] + radius * cos(t)
    y = center[1] + radius * sin(t)
    return np.append(x, (center[0], x[0])), np.append(y, (center[1], y[0]))


x_points = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y_points = [1, 2, 3, 4]
ab = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [3, 7], [15, 2]]
radius = 0.4
colors = ["yellow", "red"]

fig = go.Figure()

for x, y, (a, b) in zip(x_points, y_points, ab):
    ratio = a / (a + b)
    for start_angle, end_angle, color in zip(
        (0, 360 * ratio), (360 * ratio, 359.9), colors
    ):
        x_disk, y_disk = disk_part([x, y], radius, start_angle, end_angle)
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                x=x_disk,
                y=y_disk,
                fill="toself",
                fillcolor=color,
                line={"color": color},
                name=f"{(end_angle-start_angle)/360 * 100:.1f}%",
            )
        )

fig.update_yaxes(scaleanchor="x", scaleratio=1)
fig.show()
```

With such x_points  and y_points, the output satisfies. But if x_points = [0.39, 0.17, 0.12, 1.2], and y_points = [210, 160, 150, 250], then the output will be ugly. How to choose colorscale for different maststabs x_points and y_points or some other solution?

I tried to normalize the values( y_points / max(y_points) ) and when plotting on the axis, write the necessary
tickvals=y_tick/max_y,
ticktext=y_tick.
But it didn't help.

Comment: [Please don't repost questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7054/248627)

Comment: Two users helpfully asked for clarification in comments, and you have ignored them. One user provided a pretty comprehensive-looking answer, which you also seem to have ignored. Please respect our time. Reposting questions, especially after wasting other users' time, isn't a very good way to get free help.